# Cant "require" rethinkdb with aurelia skeleton

Tags: aurelia, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I've set up a vanilla typeform aurelia project with the cli, and installed the rethinkdb driver. From the terminal I can start node and access the rethinkdb without problems, but from app.ts I can't. It does not locate the rethinkdb files within node_modules and I can't figure out why...

In my app.ts I have:

```
var r = require("rethinkdb");

export class App {

  connectToRethinkDB(){
    var connection = null;
    r.connect( {host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn) {
      if (err) throw err;
      connection = conn;
    })
  }
}
```

My project file structure is this

[image: project file structure]

Comment: I gave up on this and no longer relevant (to me)